# Generating a plane of best fit

Tags: linear-algebra, matlab

I am working on some matlab code trying to generate a plane of best fit. However, I don't have a set of points, the only given information is two angles (the pitch and yaw). Is there a way to go about this? 
Thanks much,
Andy

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good
question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: You can make a normal vector in your coordinate system pointing in same direction as planes equation if pitch and yaw = 0 and then you rotate it according to the definition of pitch and yaw. You can probably do the rotation by multiplying the vector with rotation matrices.